# Simulate Arellano-Bond

Tags: panel-data, simulation

I have fitted a dynamic panel data model with Arellano-Bond estimator in gretl, here is the output:

```
Model 5: 2-step dynamic panel, using 2332 observations
Included 106 cross-sectional units
H-matrix as per Ox/DPD
Dependent variable: trvr

              coefficient   std. error     z       p-value 
  ---------------------------------------------------------
  Dtrvr(-1)    0.895381     0.0248490    36.03    2.55e-284 ***
  const        0.0230952    0.00226823   10.18    2.39e-024 ***
  x1          -0.0263556    0.00836633   -3.150   0.0016    ***
  x2           0.127888     0.0171532     7.456   8.94e-014 ***

Sum squared resid    605.9396   S.E. of regression   0.510180

Number of instruments = 256
Test for AR(1) errors: z = -4.29161 [0.0000]
Test for AR(2) errors: z = 1.62503 [0.1042]
Sargan over-identification test: Chi-square(252) = 105.139 [1.0000]
Wald (joint) test: Chi-square(3) = 2333.35 [0.0000]
```

I have 2 questions about the results:

1. How do I assess the fit?
2. How can I simulate from the model?

Comment: @teucer, what do you mean by simulate? You want to get the forecasts?

Comment: @mpiktas I want  to plug in new values for x1, x2 and  get the probability distribution for trvr (which should be the sum of two normals, right?). So it is a simulation and not a  forecast...

Comment: @teucer, in general Arrelano-Bond estimator does not assume normality. Furthermore it is used to estimate conditional expectation $E(y|x)$, so it is not a good idea to use it for simulating the probability distribution of $y$.

Comment: @mpiktas thx for the explanation. I tried a mixed effect model (lme4), the problem is somehow the fitted values (lme4::fitted) are strangely close to trvr(-1) instead of trvr. Is that normal?what can be the problem?

Comment: @teucer, mixed effect models are not appropriate when lagged dependent variables are used. This is a standard result which is discussed in all books which describe dynamic panel regression. The problem is that lagged variable correlates with the random effect (in mixed effect model parlance, it is individual effect in panel data terminology).

Comment: @teucer, you will need to specify the error distribution also. Even then it will not be trivial if normality is not assumed. For normality assumption you will need to test whether your residuals are normal.

Comment: @mpiktas how can I model such systems then? The goal is to simulate next year's values. (I have mistakenly deleted my previous comment: can't I assume distributions for x1,x2 and derive a distribution for trvr in Arellano-Bond (AB) setup? Btw, the AB fitted values are also close to trvr(-1), is that normal?)

Comment: @teucer, why do you insist on simulating? If you want to get the feel how model works for different future values of `x1` and `x2`, simply plug them into model and calculate `trvr`. What is the purpose of your simulation?

Comment: @mpiktas OK, I can do that. But why are the AB fitted values close to trvr(-1)?

Comment: @teucer, look at the coefficients, lag coefficient is 0.9, this is very large. This means that almost everything is explained by the lagged value. If the values of x1 and x2 are small they contribute little, since the corresponding coefficients for the them and the constant are small.